# Windows 10 won't wake from sleep after update 1511

Tags: windows-10, sleep, windows-10-v1511

I installed the update to Windows 10 version 1511 at the end of November and have since been unable to wake my system after sleep.  The system starts to wake after a keyboard interaction (lights on, fans, disk spinning), but the screen stays dark.  After 30+ seconds the system reboots itself and I can log in, but obviously loose any application state from sleep.

After a couple of these reboot occurrences Windows offered to fix my install and one of the options was to roll back to previous build.  This fixed the issue, pointing to update 1511 as the culprit.  However, I know Microsoft's philosophy for Win 10 is that updates are required (OS as a service), so this is not a long term, nor maybe even short term solution.

I reinstalled the update 1511 proactively and the wake after sleep issue returned.

Has anyone discovered a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have read many complaints on many windows versions regarding waking from sleep
mode. I have never used it(very ill advised for laptops). have you considered
changing your presets to hibernate?(more reliable, harder to corrupt). failing
that option, perhaps you could get in the habit of executing screen lock
(windows key + l) every time you leave your computer.  just a thought.

Comment: I appreciate the alternate idea, but I'm hoping for a work around to get Sleep to work once again.  Locking isn't really an option because I don't want the power bill of leaving the computer on all the time.  My understanding is that sleep is a hybrid of hibernate and low power mode.  Goes into low power mode immediately and shuffles to disk via hibernate in the background in case of power loss.

Comment: hibernate writes a file to your c drive and shuts down completely  resuming after hibernate typically takes around 15 seconds, depending on how much of memory Is being used. it uses far less power than sleep.