# Why doesn't my windows 11 laptop always wake from sleep?

Tags: windows-11, sleep

When I close the lid of my laptop, I have it to set to go to sleep mode. If I open the lid shortly after, it doesn't *always* wake from sleep mode. If it doesn't, the only life sign from my laptop is the power button LED that slowly fades in and out. Pressing the power button doesn't do anything, nor does pressing any key on the keyboard or moving the mouse. However, sometimes the sleep mode does work as expected, but I don't know why or when.

This issue if different from [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1013809/windows-10-wont-wake-from-sleep-after-update-1511) that was caused after a Windows 10 update, or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1602398/laptop-goes-to-sleep-then-into-a-coma-wont-wake-up-by-keyboard-mouse) that only occurs after a prolonged several hours sleep period.

### System details

| Item | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| OS Name | Microsoft Windows 11 Business |
| Version | 10.0.22631 Build 22631 |
| System Manufacturer | LENOVO |
| System Model | 20VX0065MZ |
| System Type | x64-based PC |
| System SKU | LENOVO_MT_20VX_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad P14s Gen 2i |
| Processor | 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2803 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 7 Logical Processor(s) |
| BIOS Version/Date | LENOVO N34ET59W (1.59 ), 07/11/2023 |
| SMBIOS Version | 3.2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by a mode called "Away Mode" on Windows. I found the fix thanks to this [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/tz5j0f/comment/iafgq77/).

### The fix

1. Open Control **Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings**
2. Select **Change advanced power settings**
3. Select **No** for both battery and the plugged in state under **Sleep > Allow Away Mode Policy**

   [image: disable away mode]

For me, the away mode was enabled when the laptop was plugged in, but not when on battery. That's why the sleep mode sometimes worked and other times not.

If you do not see this option in your Power Options, as was the case for me, you can enable it by:

1. Opening a command prompt in administrator mode.
2. Run the following command to enable this option in your power settings: `REG ADD     HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\25DFA149-5DD1-4736-B5AB-E8A37B5B8187 /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f`

For other ways to enable this option, see [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108441-add-remove-allow-away-mode-policy-power-options-windows.html).

### The problem

According to the [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/tz5j0f/comment/iafgq77/):

> your pc is going into "Away mode" and wont proceed to sleep it turns off monitor and other devices including your mouse and keyboard but leaves other parts on... resulting in not being able to wake it up.